# Correct implementation of NSObject description method for nested classes containing collections

Tags: iphone

With my own classes, I usually override -(NSString *)description method to ease debugging. 
However when invoking description on a class that I implemented that calls recursively description method from my other classes, all formatting characters from the 'deeper' classes are escaped. That makes any pretty printing difficult to implement. 
Here's an example to make it clearer:

```
@interface Foo {
    NSArray *barsArray;
}
@end
@implementation Foo
- (NSString *)description {
    return [NSString stringWithFormat: @"foo contents: %@", barsArray];
}

@interface Bar {
    NSString *s1;
    NSString *s2;
}
@implementation Bar
- (NSString *)description {
    return [NSString stringWithFormat: @"s1: %@\ns2: %@", s1, s2];
}
```

In this case, the \n newline characters from description of class B will get escaped in the output of class A description method. Any idea how to get rid or circumvent this behaviour? It's especially annoying when printing nested classes that all contain collections.

Comment: If I take your implementation, making barsArray a Bar*, and then call print-object on a Foo object, the newline is correctly printed, not escaped. Where exactly is your problem?

Comment: if instead of an array of Bar you'll have a single Bar* element that you're right, everything will be printed correctly. However with the array, it seems that the description method for array, escapes the strings that are returned from calling description on array elements

Answer (score 2):

You can always make use of the nice formatting that the standard containers come with. For example, your Bar description could be:

```
- (id)containerDescription {
  return [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:s1, @"s1", s2, @"s2", nil];
}

- (NSString *)description {
  return [self.containerDescription description];
```

You can now do the following on Foo:

```
- (NSString *)description {
  NSArray *desc = [barsArray valueForKey:@"containerDescription"];
  NSDictionary *descriptionDictionary =
    [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:desc, @"foo contents", nil];
  return [descriptionDictionary description];
}
```

The solution is not optimal of course, as you have to have a second method and have to call the containerDescription on higher levels, but it's the only one I found yet.

Comment: no, this does not work. It has exactly the same problem as described above - and this is because the description method for array seems to escape the output returned from description methods called on array elements. With your particular code, and assuming that we init s1 = @"s1 string" and s2 = @"s2 string", what we get is: 
foo contents: (
    "{\n    s1 = \"s1 string\";\n    s2 = \"s2 string\";\n}",
    "{\n    s1 = \"s1 string\";\n    s2 = \"s2 string\";\n}"
)
Exactly with these annoying \n characters I wannted to get rid of in the first place.

Comment: Ah, thanks for clearing it up, of course. I updated the code now to something that works with the array of Bars.

Comment: Yeah, the problem is that when your hierarchy is much deeper it becomes kind of tedious. 
The other solution I've found was to unescape the description string at the top level. But that's a rather gross hack.

Comment: Tedious, well, somehow. But if you make the description that calls the containerDescription the default in an NSObject Category, you only have to implement one method per class. And writing a dictionary or array object instead of an NSString format is actually not that much more work.

Comment: +1 Adding containerDescription as a category on NSObject, NSArray, and NSDictionary works great.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a carriage return `\r` which will end up in a new line too (even in a NSArray's description).
But it will not indent the output. In my case I have just added 8 spaces (`\t` will be escaped too) which will look nice for plain and array output, but not as nice as it could be for deeper structures.